# Pointer taking input infinitely

Tags: c

I have following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char p[12], i;

    for(i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", p+i);
    }

    for(i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", *(p+i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code is taking input infinitely. Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Really??? works fine here. But compiler warns `warning: format %d expects argument of type int *, but argument 2 has type char *`.

Comment: It's working fine in my compiler. which compiler are you using??

Comment: I an using Codeblocks.

Comment: How are you providing input?  By "taking input infinitely", do you mean that it is just sitting there waiting for you to enter data?  (That would be the expected behavior if you run this with stdin attached to a tty)

Comment: **`%d`** and **`char []`** **???** Do you want to read integers or characters?

Comment: @herohuyongtao, oops sorry!! I want to read integer. Now it is working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are messing up `int` and `char` (format specifier `%d` is for integers, not characters). Please refer to [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) for more info of format specifiers for different types.

If you want to read integers from user, you need to change your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p[12], i;

    for(i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &p[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", *(p+i)); // or better to use p[i] here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The counter **i** is declared as a **character** in your code. This will lead to a logical error while executing the for loop.

So decare the variable `i`  as follows,

```
int i;
```

Also change the format specifier to `%c` to handle the input properly.